# pass dynamic props in jxs using string literal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I know we can setState or get state on dynamic variables

like `` this.state[`id-$(id)`] `` or `this.state[someVariable]` but can we pass dynamic props down to children component?

```
<div what_to_do_here={this.state[`id-${id}`]} />hello</div>
```

Comment: So did it work?

Comment: You want id to be provided by a child component right?

Answer (score 1):

one way to do it is by using an object to gather your props + the spread operator (ES2015).

```
  render() {
    const myProps = { a: 4, f: 1 };
    return <Application {...myProps} />;
  }
```